# Attach and run a command in a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running /bin/bash

So I can attach to it and run commands like

```
docker attach <container id>
bash# apt-get install package
```

Is there a way I can do this in a single docker command instead, maybe something like this:

```
docker attach <container id> "apt-get install package"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

`echo 'sudo apt-get install package' | docker attach <container id>`

Comment: thanks, thats a nice workaround, but is there also a way to then see the output of that command on stdout?

Comment: How about
`echo 'sudo apt-get install package' | docker attach <container id> && docker logs -f <container id>` ?